# sql dedupe based on master child relationship

Tags: .net, sql, relational-database

I have 2 tables (master and child)

Master Table (Person)

PersonID    Name          Age         SSN

1             Saurabh   12            1234

2                      Saurabh    13            1234

3                      Saurabh    14             4567

Child Table (Order)

OrderID|PersonID|ItemID|Quantity

1    1             1          1

2               1             2          1

3               2             1          1

4               2             2          1

5               3             1          1

I need to delete all the duplicate records in persons table based on following dedupe condition.2 persons are duplicate if they have same Name, SSN and ordersets. In this example Persons with ID 1 and 2 are duplicate because they have same Name (Saurabh), SSN (1234) and  orders.

It’s easy to perform dedupe on a single table, but I am not getting efficient way of doing if you have parent child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe the following will give you the results you are looking.  I would run the query without the delete portion first and verify the results.

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE PersonID IN 
(
  SELECT P.PersonID
  FROM Person AS P
  INNER JOIN [Order] AS O 
  ON P.PersonID = O.PersonID
  WHERE P.PersonID IN 
  (
    SELECT IP.PersonID
    FROM Person AS IP
    INNER JOIN [Order] AS IO 
    ON IP.PersonID = IO.PersonID
    WHERE IP.PersonID <> P.PersonID
    AND IP.Name = P.Name
    AND IP.SSN = P.SSN
    AND O.ItemID = IO.ItemID 
    AND O.Quantity = IO.Quantity
  )
)
```